# using DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter with default client validation rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, data-annotations

i need to use resources for getting the error message for data annotations attributes.
im doing this with registering a DataAnnotationAdapter in global.asax

here is my adapter

```
public class ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<ValidationAttribute>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The type of the resource which holds the error messqages
        /// </summary>
        public static Type ResourceType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Function to get the ErrorMessageResourceName from the Attribute
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<ValidationAttribute, string> ResourceNameFunc
        {
            get { return _resourceNameFunc; }
            set { _resourceNameFunc = value; }
        }
        private static Func<ValidationAttribute, string> _resourceNameFunc = attr => attr.GetType().Name;

        public ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, ValidationAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {   
            if (Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType == null)
            {
                this.Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = ResourceType;
            }

            if (Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
            {
                this.Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourceNameFunc(this.Attribute);
            }

        }

    }
```

and here is how i register it in my global.asax

```
ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator.ResourceType = typeof(Resources);
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RangeAttribute), typeof(ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), typeof(ExternalResourceDataAnnotationsValidator));
```

this code doesn't provide client validation because it doesnt return any clientvalidationrules

my question is how can i know the ValidationType to put in method below

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            var rm = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
            var msg =rm.GetString(ResourceNameFunc(this.Attribute));
            return new[] {new ModelClientValidationRule() {ErrorMessage = msg, ValidationType ="??????"},};
        }
```